# Angular 2 Meteor initial load is so slow

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, meteor, angular2-meteor

I'm currently developing a web app that is built with Meteor angular 2 stack and also using angular2 material for ui.

The problem is initial load time is so slow that it takes 7-8 seconds to fully load with good internet connection speed.

Meteorjs main javascript file is 565 kb. It also contains angular 2 scripts.

I have made some research and saw Ahead of time, three shaking and lazy loading concepts but I couldn't manage to work them with meteor. :(

So I need your help and advices right now.

[image: This is the meteor js file timing]

Comment: The reason is Just-in-time compiler. The browser does not use the compiled js files without Aot as you already know. With Jit, the browser "re"-compiles your app inside the browser. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#overview So you need Aot + tree shaking :/

Comment: Thank you , but do you have any experience with meteor + angular 2 aot + tree shaking, did you tried or at least have any resource that i can look at ?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( Hope someone will answer or write a documentation about this.